# Gruntfile.js - Task “default” not found.... again

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

```
'use strict';
module.export = function(grunt) {
    //time how long tasks take can help when optimizing  buildtime
    require('time.grunt')(grunt);
    //automatically load required grunt tasks
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

//define the configuration off all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obivious mistakes 
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '/app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]

        }
    }

});

grunt.registerTask('build', ['jshint']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
};
```

I am solving an assignment from Front-End JavaScript Frameworks: `AngularJS` course.
The above code was supplied by the course instructor, I just pasted it in my `Gruntfile.js` 
 I am getting warning:

> warning task default not found.use --force to continue

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's typo. It should be `module.exports = function...`.